# Detecting IIS Activity

Tags: .net, asp.net, iis, webserver

For an ASP.NET application, is there a way to tell whether anyone is connected to the application, or if the web server is idle with no connections?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't have any experience with any, but have you looked at IIS tracing or performance monitoring tools? Some quick digging revealed quite a few.

Comment: Not quite looking for a tool, but want to build an app to manage a feature using this information...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[WMI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394582.aspx) can be used to get the status of the web server (see [this](http://www.motobit.com/tips/detpg_wmi-iis-performance/) post for an example).  I am not sure on checking the startup status of the application.  Perhaps if it were in its own AppPool, you could check the status of the pool.

Comment: OK, it is in its own app pool actually, so that is a possibility.  thanks.